# Using adaptive cards with incoming webhooks

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it in any way possible to send an AdaptiveCard through an incoming webhook and display it in Microsoft Teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only Actionable Cards are supported in webhooks. Please see this reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook.

If you need to use Adaptive Cards, you'll need to create a bot to send messages. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots